# CGPath curve line flickering with black filling, when fill is set to clear color

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, cgpath

Simple sin wave CGPath.

When added to layer flickering with black color, video:

https://gfycat.com/PaleIllAustraliansilkyterrier

Photo(it appears like this for milliseconds):

[image]

```
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

I remember that experienced something like this couple of years ago and make some workaround, but now I can't find exact project.

I'm already checked that width of view can be divided by length of wave, but no luck.

Some community thoughts? Have you ever experienced this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flickering comes probably from setting the fill color. You should set this color to either the background color or (better) `nil` which [avoids filling](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer/1522248-fillcolor). Clear color and no color are not the same.

Comment: Setting to nil makes zero-effect. If I comment it, it is filling with black.

Comment: What is the background color from the shape layer? Would you please insert a code example for the animation and the complete layer configuration?

Comment: This is the point - as a background there can be a camera view. Code you can find here: https://github.com/soggybag/Sine-Wave/blob/master/Sine%20Wave/SineWaveView.swift, drawSineWaves function.

Comment: Unfortunately, your code has some dependencies and replies to a previous Swift version, so can't get it run quickly. However, I would highly recommend you to animate the path with a `CABasicAnimation` or `CAKeyFrameAnimation`. This will give you a better performance and will probably avoid the flickering.

Comment: OK, I've just put `sine.shapeLayer.fillColor = nil` in top of `viewDidLoad` and it stop to flicker.